# Top alignment of cell content not working in tabular

Tags: tables, alignment

I would like to align contents of cell to top. I used pos [t] option in tabular to do this. However, the contents are not getting top aligned despite my explicit mention. Any suggestion on this would be very helpful. Thank you.

```
\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\arraybackslash}m{11cm}}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\arraybackslash}m{1.8cm}}
\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \caption{Notations for MIP models}
    \scalebox{0.9}{
        \begin{tabular}[t]{YrZ}
            \toprule
            \textbf{Type} & \textbf{Notation} & \textbf{Definition} \\
            \midrule
            Set definitions & $\mathcal{S}$ & Collection of all node subsets $S \subset N$ such that $0 \in S$, $2n+1 \notin S$, and there exists a node $i \in P$ such that $i \notin S$ and $n+i \in S$\\[0.45cm]
            &$\Omega$ & Collection of node subsets $S \subset P \cup D$ such that there is at least one customer order $j \in P$ such that either $j \in S$ and $n+j \notin S$ or $n+j \in S$ and $j \notin S$ \\[0.45cm]
            &$A'$ & Subset of arcs having both endpoints in $P \cup D$\\[0.45cm]
            &$\Upsilon_j$ & Collection of all node subsets $S \subset P \cup D$ such that $j \in S$ and $n+j \notin S$\\
            \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \label{tab:not1}
\end{table}
```

This is the output I get. As you can see, column 2 contents are not top aligned
[image: Problem illustration]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Change the column type from `m` ("m" is for "middle") to `p`.

Comment: avoid using `\scalebox` on tables, only use it as an absolute last resort (but even then try to avoid it). If you do use it, you want `\scalebox{0.9}{%` not `\scalebox{0.9}{` as you are adding space to the left of the table.

Comment: Thank you for the valuable tip David. I will avoid scalebox for now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `t` in `\begin{tabular}[t]{YrZ}` does stand for "top". However, it refers to the placement of the entire `tabular` environment with respect to other items in the same row, **not** to the placement of cell contents within the `tabular` environment itself. In the case of your code, the `t` placement specifier has no effect at all since there are no other items in the row that contains the `tabular` environment.

Your use of the `m` -- `m` stands for "middle" -- column type in the definitions of the `Y` and `Z` column types (employed in columns 1 and 3) *forces* LaTeX to center the other cells -- here, column 2 -- vertically.

What to do? Replace `m` with `p` in the definitions of `Y` and `Z`.

---

Your LaTeX code could stand some clean-up and simplification. For instance, your settings for the `Y` and `Z` columns apparently make the `tabular` environment wider than the text block; this, in turn, forces you to clean up the mess by placing the `tabular` in a `\scalebox` environment. Presumably, but not necessarily, the `0.9` scaling factor is good enough to force the tabular material back inside the text block. A cleaner setup would employ a `tabularx` environment (with overall width equal to `\textwidth`) and use that package's `X` column type for the third column; the width an `X` column is computed dynamically by LaTeX. A separate issue: the `[0.45ex]` extra spacing directive has no effect whatsoever in several cases. I suggest that since you employ the `booktabs` package, use that package's `\addlinespace` macro instead.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{1.6cm}} % 'p', not 'm'
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}

\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{Notation for MIP models}
\label{tab:not1}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} YrL @{}}
\toprule
Type & Notation & Definition \\
\midrule
Set definitions 
  & $\mathcal{S}$ 
  & Collection of all node subsets $S \subset N$ such that $0 \in S$, $2n+1 \notin S$, and there exists a node $i \in P$ such that $i \notin S$ and $n+i \in S$\\ 
\addlinespace
  &$\Omega$ 
  & Collection of node subsets $S \subset P \cup D$ such that there is at least one customer order $j \in P$ such that either $j \in S$ and $n+j \notin S$ or $n+j \in S$ and $j \notin S$ \\ 
\addlinespace
  &$A'$ & Subset of arcs having both endpoints in $P \cup D$\\ 
\addlinespace
  &$\Upsilon_j$ & Collection of all node subsets $S \subset P \cup D$ such that $j \in S$ and $n+j \notin S$\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh, wow! Thank you so much for answering my question and furthermore, providing a cleanup tip. Really made my life easier.